# How do I diagnose a crash?

Tags: error

How do I determine the cause of a crash? I get no crash file. I updated my graphics driver recently (NVIDIA GTX 1650 SUPER). It happens about a minute after I switch from displaying in Solid Mode to Material Mode (or to Render Mode, but takes longer). I never see my scene in material mode. Objects turn white immediately and stay that way. Blender memory usage starts out less than 1G, then slowly rises to about 12G (out of my 16G), then slowly bounces around down to around 3.5G then crashes. I started Blender from the command line with --factory-startup --debug-all. Since there was no crash file, I trapped the console output, although it may be useless, except perhaps the last line. It can be seen [here](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZAEz9XZyNpbaNFIinyBK7Ext2S95jbmgj4V) (1.5MB). The file that caused the crash is [here](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZGNz9XZplqwhpkejobC70GkxpdGzFpJWca7) (19MB).

Comment: Did you mean to attach that body to that title?  The two seem completely unrelated.

Comment: Thanks. My cookies for this forum had a mind of their own. I edited the title.

Comment: You could report a graphics card bug/crash [Here](https://developer.blender.org/) and send them the txt that you have

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does Blender store log information?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145223/where-does-blender-store-log-information) tldr : Assuming you're on windows, in your blender installation, there is a file called `blender_debug_log.cmd`. Launch it instead of the standard `blender.exe`