# Why has blender 3.5 suddenly stopped showing textures render viewport shading? and crashing if i switch back to material preview?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I sat down to work, and opened up the .blend file i was working on. Everything looked fine in material preview viewport window until i switched to render preview view.

Image is of my material preview looks fine.

[image: material preview]

When i went to work in render preview, this is what i see:

[image: render preview]

Then, when i try to go back to the material preview, blender crashes.

Any ideas? It just started doing it today.

Yesterday i updated windows 11, and updated the nvidia gameready drivers for Diablo 4. I did not run blender after that, so i have to assume this is the cause of the issue.

Today I have tried: switching nvidia gameready drivers back to creative drivers. Uninstalling Blender 3.5.1 and re-installing. (Running the file in Blender 3.4 worked for a bit, but after a couple crashes (and loss of a couple hours work) it started doing the same thing.) Nothing is visible in the render preview except my rig. Anything with a texture is showing as dark grey silhouette.

Next i guess i can try rolling back my Windows 11 update. and if that does nothing, maybe roll back my graphic drivers as well (although the nvidia creative drivers aren't updated as frequently as gameready drivers, so i doubt it would have much effect since i was working fine with them a few days ago).

Anyone know why its happening?

Machine is a Threadripper 32 with geforce 4090.

Comment: Ok i have narrowed down the problem a bit. I rolled back my windows drivers. I rolled back my nvidia drivers. With absolutely zero effect. Still crashes when i switch to render preview. I did notice something however. When i go into settings and turn off the GPU and only have the CPU, it works. As soon as i re-enable the GPU to help with rendering, and switch to render preview, it crashes. Games run fine, but blender is broken. It does it in all versions of blender. Instant crash if i try to use GPU. Very frustrating.

Comment: The crash logs would be helpful to diagnose the issue, you can find them here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145223/where-does-blender-store-log-information
And you can also create a bug report under the help section

Comment: This is a Q&A site run by volunteers. No-one here is a Blender developer or has any association with the Blender Foundation and questions about crashes are specifically discouraged here. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. You should report any suspected bugs via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to why the render shading looks like your 2nd screenshot is in front your eyes:

[image]

You've got to wait a bit. It can take seconds or minutes.

As for why it crashes when you switch back to material shading, maybe try again *after* Blender is done retrieving the kernels. And if it doesn't help:
Go to the menu Help > Report a bug.