# Blender 3.5.1 crashing on powerful PC

Tags: rendering

I upgraded to a new PC and Blender worked fine initially but now seems to crash a lot, especially when changing the viewport display mode - or rendering.

The file isn't especially complex, 109k vertices, 7 lights, simple animations.

PC specs:

CPU = i9 13900k

GPU = GTX4090

VRAM = 128GB

Drivers are all up to date, reinstalled Blender.
I'm trying to render it at 1280x720, I've not done anything crazy with the performance settings.
I just don't know why it's doing it. It should be able to handle it, right?

Comment: Are you able to run Blender from a command line so you have the logs when it crashes?
Or have a look at the existing logs written out to the [Directory on your OS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145223/where-does-blender-store-log-information). It definitely shouldn't be crashing but it's hard to say what's going on without logs attached.

Comment: For me it's the same, i9 13900k - GTX 4070 Ti - 64 Gb RAM, Drivers Studio version, latest build. One crash after another, even with very simple scenes. My suspect is that there is something wrong with the interaction between the RTX 40__ serie and Blender.

Comment: @PatrickS - I ran it from a command line as you suggested and it crashed on frame 4, stating:  
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Address : 0x00007FFEE5227C82

Module  : tbbmalloc.dll

Thread  : 00007520

Writing: C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Temp\AntTrain7.crash.txt

Error loading symbols C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.5\blender.pdb

error:0xc0000005
size = 114454528
        base=0x00007FF744A80000
Not sure what that means but at least I have an avenue of inquiry now, thanks. :)